# How to handle Python exceptions in a decent way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, coding-style, programming-languages

I am developing an online service with python. Since it is an ONLINE service, I do not want the service down under any circumstances. So I add lots of `try.. except...` to make sure that if anything bad happens I will catch it and report it.

code like this

```py
try:
    code here
except Exception as e:
    reportException(e)

some code here # I cannot put everything in a single `try...except` statement

try:
    code here
except Exception as e:
    reportException(e)
```

I know it is a bad way as I have to use `try` several times. I want to know is it possible to do this in an elegent way?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine try statements with a loop:

```
for action in [act_1, act_2, act_3, ...]:
    try:
        action(line)
    except:
        reportException()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way is to catch exceptions at the outermost layer of your program, which is what the Django framework does. In fact, when handling exceptions, it is not recommended to catch "Exception" exceptions, but if your project is going to do this, it is more elegant to catch them at the outermost layer of the program.For example, put all your code into the "main" function, then go directly to catch the exception thrown by the "main" function.

```py
def main():
    # all your code and do not use try...except
    code here
    code here
    code here
try:
    main()
except Exception as e:
    reportException(e)
```

Comment: Indeed it is an elegant way. But I want to customize the message in `reportException` for different types of error. That's why I have to use `try` several times. Any suggestions? Probably `wrapper` is a good solution?

Comment: After "except Exception as e:", judge your various custom exceptions, and then deal with them accordingly. This is an exception handler

Comment: sorry it's my typo. The question is how to handle errors from different functions in different ways (since we put all code in main)?